# Is there any documentation on the interdependencies between packages in the scipy, numpy, pandas, scikit ecosystem? Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pandas, scikit-learn

Is there any documentation on the interdependencies and relationship between packages in the the scipy, numpy, pandas, scikit ecosystem?

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, here is the dependency tree (numpy is a dependency of everything):

- numpy

  - scipy

    - scikit-learn
  - pandas

Answer (score 0):

[Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkgs.html)
has nice conda-meta files that list requirements of 100-odd packages.
This [gist](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz/6194276) has a short shell script
that summarizes that info; for example, in August (excluding numpy) --

```
pandas-0.11.0-np17py27_1.json       dateutil 2.1     pytz 2013b     scipy 0.12.0
statsmodels-0.4.3-np17py27_1.json   pandas 0.11.0    scipy 0.12.0
...
```